# JSONException never thrown in corresponding try statement

Tags: java, android

```
@Override
public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args, CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {
    try {
        if (action.equals("init")) {    
            ctrl = io.display.sdk.Controller.getInstance();
            ctrl.getInstance().init(cordova.getActivity().getBaseContext(), "5017");                
        } else if (action.equals("showAds")) {
            ctrl.setEventListener(new EventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onInit() {
                    ctrl.showAd("1445");
                }
            });
            callbackContext.success("");
        } 
        return true;

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        callbackContext.error("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        return false;      
    }         
}
```

I get the following error when executing this code:

> JSONException never thrown in corresponding try/catch body statement.

Can you explain me why this exception is thrown? The syntax looks okay to me.

Comment: This time I did it for you, but use indentation please, we can help but you have to help us understand

Comment: ok, thx, approved

Comment: Np, exactly where is the error thrown? which line?

Comment: @PierGiorgioMisley line 54, exception JSONException is never thrown in body of corresponding try statement

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is you are having JSONArray as a parameter but you never used it inside your method. Hence JSON related exception will not be thrown.

The catch block should catch the possible exceptions thrown by the try block

Comment: This method cannot be used because it's not triggered yet. I want just to build, not using method yet.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using throws for method, you need to surround your try catch block around the function call.

Comment: i'm not calling this method anywhere, want to build, its unused for now

Comment: Try removing throws declaration

Answer (score 0):

the two statements `Throws JSONException` and `try-catch` can replace each others.

Remove the `throws JSONException` from the signature and the exception will go inside the try body

Comment: it was not this

Comment: @ŁukaszMaćczak which is the exception message?

Comment: There is no exception message, compiler will not pass it.

Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
H:\display.io.plugin\platforms\android\src\com\phonegap\plugins\displayio\Display.java:62: error: exception JSONException is never thrown in body of corresponding try statement
  catch (JSONException e) {
  ^
1 error

Comment: and line 54 appears

Comment: @ŁukaszMaćczak yeah but which line is the 54? we don't have line numbers